# TypeError when saving a formset

Tags: django, django-forms

I've declared a formset like so:

```
class BaseFeatureFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def save(self, commit = True):
        feature = Feature(name = self.cleaned_data['name'], 
                     type = self.cleaned_data['type'], 
                     premium = self.cleaned_data['premium'],)
        feature.save()
        return feature


FeaturesFormset = formset_factory(EditFeatureForm, 
                                  formset = BaseFeatureFormSet, extra = 0)
```

So when I'm saving the formset, I'm getting a TypeError: `list indices must be integers, not str`  referring to the first line of the `save()` function.  How do I solve this error?

**Update 1**
Managed to solve this first bit thanks to gruszyczy. I'm not getting another TypeError: `'EditFeatureFormFormSet' object is not iterable` from the next line in the code section:

```
for feature in features:
    feature.save()
    feature = vehicle.features.add(feature)
```

The error is from `for feature in features:`  Ideas?

Comment: Present whole new save function and we can talk :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cleaned_data` in this example is a list of form values. You have to iterate over it and inside you will find data you need:

```
for values in self.cleaned_data:
    feature = Feature(name=values['name'], ..
```

That's because formset is a list of forms, that are displayed and returns a list of form values. This is a simple concept to grasp, when you simple realise, that FormSet <-> [Form, Form, Form, ..]

Comment: This works....but then the next line in my code is giving another TypeError...let me edit my question

Comment: Used the same method, but eliminated the save() function and instead did a for feature in features.cleaned_data loop within the view.  Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is `features` defined as a list/tuple?

Comment: I think you have a point there...as the save() function will always save the first item no matter how many features are there in the formset.  I'm stuck here